# React Native Task :app:processDebugResources Failed to execute aapt

Tags: java, android, react-native

I had no problem building my project in debug. I just installed a new npm package(bugsnag) then did react-native link now I cant build it anymore. I tried many suggested solutions from google none of them worked.

Strange part I tried to build backup file of my project and its not building also with same errors, so feels like its connected with something else?

Bug details:

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources
Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

....

> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
>   process
>   C:\Users\eless\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe
>   with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I
>   C:\Users\eless\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar
>   -M \?\D:\React\swipe-app-developp\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
>   -S D:\React\swipe-app-developp\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug
>   -m -J \?\D:\React\swipe-app-developp\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug
>   -F D:\React\swipe-app-developp\android\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_
>   -D \?\D:\React\swipe-app-developp\android\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\manifest_keep.txt
>   --custom-package xx.com.xx -0 apk --output-text-symbols \?\D:\React\swipe-app-developp\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
>   --no-version-vectors}

```
Error while executing process C:\Users\eless\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe with arguments
```

> app\build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 24
        versionName "1.0.23"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
             abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "xx4",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }

dependencies {
    compile project(':bugsnag-react-native')
    compile project(':lottie-react-native')
    compile project(':react-native-fast-image')
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
    compile project(':react-native-android-permissions')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-iap')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'
    // From node_modules
}
```

Comment: any help is accepted.. thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried different ways and found out a proper solution I think.

in android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties

I changed

```
from
```

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

```
to
```

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

Hope it may help you..

Comment: Comment if it will help you out, then I can tag it as proper answer.